# Saving data containing categorical data to libsvm format in spark decision tree

Tags: python, scala, apache-spark, tree, bigdata

For using "MLUtils.saveAsLibSVMFile" the data parameter should be RDD of labeled points.Suppose we have 3 categories in categorical variable(which is response variable).How can we create RDD of labeled points with 3 categories as labels? I already converted my categorical variable to binary features.

```
I am trying with this code.

 from pyspark.mllib.regression import LabeledPoint
 from pyspark import SparkContext
 sc=SparkContext()
 laxman = sc.textFile("G:\converted data.txt")
 labeled_point_rdd=laxman.map(lambda row: row.split(',')).map(lambda seq:      LabeledPoint(seq[-3],seq[:-4]))

 print (labeled_point_rdd.take(2))
```